# Spring boot - write to IBM Mq multi-thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multithreading, ibm-mq

I have a Spring Boot app that uses multithreading (by the @Async annotation with an associated TaskPoolExecutor). On each thread I would like to write a message to a IBM MQ queue - the same one.

I know listening on a queue with multiple threads is possible (if you are ready to give up ordering), but is it also possible when writing to a queue?

I would be writing to the queue using JmsTemplate.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes you can have more than one producer.